# Instagram JSON avatar extraction PHP

Tags: php, json, instagram

I want to extract the profile_picture of any instagram user from the JSON url: https://www.instagram.com/just/media/ with PHP and print it out. I've tried:

```
$instaJSONUrl = 'https://www.instagram.com/just/media/';
$json = file_get_contents($instaJSONUrl);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json_data["profile_picture"];
```

Not working.. If I print out the $json only, I get:

```
{status":"ok","items":[],"more_available":false}
```

Meaning that the problem is with reading the URL. Does this mean I need access token, because I don't want to use one, as I already can get the profile image URL when I open https://www.instagram.com/just/media/ from my browser.

Answer (score 1):

This will result in an array of users and their picture profile links.

```
<?php

$instaJSONUrl = 'https://www.instagram.com/just/media/';
$json = file_get_contents($instaJSONUrl);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);

$users = array();

foreach($json_data['items'] as $item)
    foreach($item['comments'] as $comment)
            foreach($comment as $profile)
                    $users[$profile['from']['username']] = $profile['from']['profile_picture'];


print_r($users);
```

Comment: The problem is that it cannot access the whole JSON as it does when you open it through your browser. Basically it reads it as: {status":"ok","items":[],"more_available":false}, so it doesn't have any items. Check out the solution I got :-)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it via accessing the meta tags directly, and specifically the `<meta property="og:image"` tag, with the following:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$c = file_get_contents($instaURL);
$d = new DomDocument();
$d->loadHTML($c);
$xp = new domxpath($d);
```

and then I can print out the image url with:

```
foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@property='og:image']") as $el) {
   echo $el->getAttribute("content");
}
```

You can even use it to access other properties, such as `og:url` and `og:description` for the specific Instagram user.

**This is for all those people who needs to access & get Instagram user data (basic: profile_image, profile_url, profile_description, etc.), without dealing with Instagram's API.**